# Why is Bloom Effect affecting the whole scene

Tags: rendering, effects

When I add Emission to ONE material, as example an emerald on a sword and then in render settings enable Bloom, it does not really work. Because everything glows, even the floor and all is adabting the colour of the bloom/Emission. But I just want my emerald to glow realistically. Does anyone know how to do that?

Would be very happy for help!

(I'm using Blender 2.8)

Comment: Did you try cranking up the threshold value or lowering the radius/intensity?

Comment: Are you taking Yan Sculpts tutorial, i just finished it, try to increase or decrease the Threshold property, it worked for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Eevee's bloom does not affect emission specifically.  It affects the entire scene.  You do not need to have even a single emission material to get bloom.  This can be useful for, say, getting bloom off the specular reflection of something very shiny, like an earring or a sword.

What Eevee *does* have is the ability to tune the bloom *threshold*.  Bloom will only affect pixels with a value lower than this threshold.  If your emission material is the only thing that is making pixels brighter than the threshold value (as determined by strength, or a color greater than 1,1,1) then your emission will be the only thing affected by the bloom.

If you'd like to have bloom only affect emission without regard to threshold, you can't do it with out of the box Eevee settings.  You need to use compositing, either to create bloom via compositing nodes, or to composite two different renders with different visible materials and/or different bloom settings.

Answer (score -1):

Play around with the **Bloom** settings in the **Render** Tab. You'll get the required effect.

For more details, please share an **Image** which can clarify the question.